# Can I access Eero router settings through Linux

Tags: linux, router, settings

so we have a Linksys router and a eero router connected to our internet. My stepdad won’t give me the password to the eero and keeps blocking my phone and computer from accessing the router just to be an ass. I’m trying to find a way that I can access our router settings through the command line. Or if there’s a way to change the way my phone and internet show up on router so he can’t keep messing with me ? I have tried a VPN but that didn’t help. I would appreciate any help . Thanks

Comment: Neither of those routers is likely to have a command line interface, commonly SoHo devices only have a web-based GUI. Why should you be able to access the router in the first place? What exactly aren't you able to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.